# Excel VBA Create PDF using ExportAsFixedFormat frequently hangs

Tags: excel, vba, pdf-generation

I have a process that takes a series of inputs, retrieves some data, and generates a PDF in a loop.
If I test it on a single entry, it always works.      When I run it in a loop, it frequently hangs at some point.
I have isolated the issue that it always occurs on when executing the same line:

`Range("Print_Area").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDF_filename, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False`

I have confirmed that the issue is NOT the filename I am trying to save.
When I repeat the process, the same file can be produced successfully.

I have read that this issue can be related to the availability of the printer.
I have tried printing out `Application.ActivePrinter` before attempting to produce the PDF, but I get the same result before a successful attempt and an attempt that hangs Excel.

I am hitting this issue on Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO - 64 bit running in Windows 10.

I would really appreciate any suggestions how to fix this issue.

Comment: Working from the presumption that the next loop is started before the first loop is finished, you might try to interject a loop at that point that runs until the previous PDF was safely created.

Comment: Thanks for the suggest Variatus, however the call to generate the PDF is synchronous, so it is not possible to start another PDF before the previous one is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem.

It turned out that the root of the problem was data retrievals that had not completed when the process of generation the PDF started.      Once I ensured that there was no possibility of new data arriving during the PDF process, the problem disappeared.